# JQuery Validate Multiple files

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

Hi I have a multiple files to upload, I need to validate all these before submitting the form

```
<form onsubmit="return validate()">
<input type="file" name="File" class="multi" />
<input type="file" name="File" class="multi" />
<input type="file" name="File" class="multi" />
<input type="file" name="File" class="multi" />
<input type="submit" name="BtnSubmit" value="save" />
</form>
```

And the j query part

```
function validate()
{
$(".multi").each(function(){
   var files = $(this).val(); 

   if(files=='')
   { 
      alert("No document file selected");
       return false; 
   }

});
}
```

The problem is its showing the alert but still it submitting the form. How to prevent this.?

Comment: Have you tried `event.preventDefault()`?

Comment: you need to catch the submit form event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validate function is not returning false, but the .each() function is. So add validation to check if all validation passed in .each() function, otherwise return false

```
function validate() {
    var count = $(".multi").length;
    var index = 0;
    $(".multi").each(function () {
        var files = $(this).val();

        if (files == '') {
            alert("No document file selected");
            return false;
        }

        index += 1;
    });

    if (index != count) { //If the validation in .each() looping has returned false
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: But in no case it's returning the value as true.

Answer (score 0):

Returning `false` from the onsubmit handler of the form stops the submission process, but in your code you are returning `false` from the anonymous function you are giving to `$.each` instead of `validate` function.

Comment: So there is any other way to do this same thing.?

Answer (score 0):

Try out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6cU74/3/

HTML:-

```
<form id="form1" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="File" class="multi" />
    <input type="file" name="File" class="multi" />
    <input type="file" name="File" class="multi" />
    <input type="file" name="File" class="multi" />
    <input type="submit" id="BtnSubmit" value="save" />
</form>
```

JS(Using jQuery):-

```
$(function () {
    $("#BtnSubmit").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var flag = true;
        $(".multi").each(function () {
            var files = $(this).val();

            if (files == '') {
                alert("No document file selected");
                flag=false;
            }

        });
        if (true==flag){
            $("#form1").submit();
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: Make it `$("#BtnSubmit").on ('click', function (event) {` - that is the preferred method in the new jquery api